# How to give custom Id to an element in handlebars template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using ember and handlebars for template and I have a case where I need to give custom Ids to the element which is created using loops.
Something like:

```
{{#each item in list}}
    <li {{bindAttr id="item.id"+item.name}}>item.text</li>
{{/each}}
```

i wanted my id to be a sum of strings id and name. e.g. if

```
id = 3 and name = summary
```

then it should render as

```
<li id="3summary">Summary</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate in Handlebars like that, instead you'll need to either create a Handlebars helper to do that, or [create a computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) in the `Ember.Object`:

```
App.MyModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    idName: function() {
        return '%@%@'.fmt(this.get('id'), this.get('name').toLowerCase());
    }.property('id', 'name')
});
```

Please see the JSFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4th3/